# How to match a square bracket in Neo4j while doing a graph query?

Tags: graph, neo4j, cypher

I am trying to match a graph object which has a code property of such `"code": ["DAF AR Index"]`.

The query `match (n:GenericProduct {code:["DAF AR Index"]}) return n;` works as expected and the object is returned, but I have been unable to match the object either using `CONTAINS` or a regular expression. To match a single opening bracket, I have tried

```
match (n:GenericProduct)
where  n.code =~ '\[.*'
    return n;
```

the same expression with double backslashes - `n.code =~ '\\[.*'`, and finally with

```
match (n:GenericProduct)
where  n.code contains '['
    return n;
```

but so far without success. Any advice on how to proceed would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways you can find nodes that have a specific property stored as a list:

Using APOC procedures:

```
MATCH (n:GenericProduct)
WHERE apoc.meta.cypher.type(n.code) = "LIST OF STRING"
RETURN n
```

Or using a "hacky" cypher:

```
MATCH (n:GenericProduct)
WHERE size(n.code + 11) = size(n.code) + 1 
RETURN n
```

Answer (score 3):

EDITED: This is the way to do a partial search of a word inside a list. Let say, we want to find "DAF" inside code where code is a list.

```
MATCH (n:GenericProduct)
WHERE ANY(cd in n.code where cd contains 'DAF' )
RETURN n
```

> Where cd in n.code means it will check each item in n.code (list).
> then "contains" will check if any word is 'DAF' and lastly, "ANY" mean find at least one
> item on the list which has a word 'DAF'

======

The square bracket "[" is not part of the value of code, it means the value of code is a "list" and it has one item named: "DAF AR Index".  To find an item (or element) on a list, you can do below:

```
match (n:GenericProduct)
where  "DAF AR Index" in n.code  
return n;
```

Comment: thanks for the answer but I am looking for something a bit different.  If it is not part of the value,  how is it possible to find or filter all node instances where code is passed as part of a list? Thanks

Comment: please give me an example and will answer it to the best of my knowledge.